# Google AppEngine Go WebApp

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have a ReactJS based Website with GO has Webserver/Backend with a REST API approach. At least this is how it would run on a normal dedicated server.

I'm trying to move the project to the Google Cloud but I have some issues.

I kicked out all the static file serving from my GO application because the Google Guide told me that the App Engine can handle the Static File serving. But its not serving any... my app.yaml looks as follow:

> ```
> runtime: go
> env: flex
> api_version: go1.8
>
> manual_scaling:
>   instances: 1
> resources:
>   cpu: 1
>   memory_gb: 0.5
>   disk_size_gb: 10
> env_variables:ur
>   CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME: xxx
>   CLOUDSQL_USER: xxx
>   CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD: 'XXX'
>   GCLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET: xxx
>   REDIS_ADDR: "<REDIS_HOST>:<REDIS_PORT>"
>   REDIS_PASSSWORD: ""
> handlers:
> - url: /
>   mime_type: text/html
>   static_files: static/index.html
>   upload: static/index.html
>   application_readable: true
>
> - url: /public/css
>   mime_type: text/css
>   static_dir: static/public/css
>   application_readable: true
>
> - url: /public/js
>   mime_type: text/javascript
>   static_dir: static/public/js
>   application_readable: true
>
> - url: /.*
>   script: _go_app
> ```

The "static" folder is also in the project folder from where i start the deploy. How can i check if the files are even uploaded?

I always get a response from the GO Server

Answer (score 0):

The flex version does not support handlers, as far as i understand.

Comment: why would it not?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Because i cant find it in the docs and if i check "serving-static-files" it gives an example how to handle it via code. Also when i changed to the "standard version" it worked like a charm.